# How to disable CKeditor when row of GridView it's not in edit mode using C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ckeditor

I am using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) in my web application on the GridView and need to disable/enable the editor from javascript.

If the row of gridview is not in edit mode I need disable the editor else I need enable the editor.

I know that there is an option called [readOnly](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.readOnly) and I have tried using `config.js`

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {

    config.removePlugins = 'bidi,image,forms,adobeair,devtools,find,maximize,a11yhelp,about,divarea,liststyle,tabletools,tableresize,contextmenu,codemirror,docprops,preview,smiley,sourcearea,save,flash,iframe,tabletools,templates,showblocks,newpage,language,print,div';

    config.width = '700';
    config.height = '200';

    config.readOnly = true;
};
```

But when the row of the gridview is not in edit mode it remains the possibility to write in the editor even if it is not possible to save the text

Does anybody know how to disable and enable back the CKEditor please?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Editor"
    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="tx1"
            runat="server"
            TextMode="MultiLine"
            Text='<%# Eval("tValue").ToString().Contains("base64") ? 
                HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("tValue").ToString()) : 
                HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Eval("tValue").ToString()) %>'
            CssClass="ckeditor"></asp:TextBox>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                CKEDITOR.replace('tx1');
            }
        </script>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to implement in gridview

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
      <title>Read-only mode</title>
      <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.19.1/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <script>
        var editor;

        // The instanceReady event is fired when an instance of CKEditor 4 has finished
        // its initialization.
        CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
          editor = ev.editor;

          // Show this "on" button.
          document.getElementById('readOnlyOn').style.display = '';

          // Event fired when the readOnly property changes.
          editor.on('readOnly', function() {
            document.getElementById('readOnlyOn').style.display = this.readOnly ? 'none' : '';
            document.getElementById('readOnlyOff').style.display = this.readOnly ? '' : 'none';
          });
        });

        function toggleReadOnly(isReadOnly) {
          // Change the read-only state of the editor.
          // https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-setReadOnly
          editor.setReadOnly(isReadOnly);
        }
      </script>
      <p>
        <input id="readOnlyOn" onclick="toggleReadOnly();" type="button" value="Make CKEditor 4 read-only" style="display:none">
        <input id="readOnlyOff" onclick="toggleReadOnly( false );" type="button" value="Make CKEditor 4 editable again" style="display:none">
      </p>
      <textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">
    &lt;h1&gt;&lt;img alt=&quot;Saturn V carrying Apollo 11&quot; class=&quot;right&quot; src=&quot;assets/sample.jpg&quot;/&gt; Apollo 11&lt;/h1&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Apollo 11&lt;/b&gt;
    was the spaceflight that landed the first humans, Americans &lt;a href=&quot;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Armstrong&quot; title=&quot;Neil Armstrong&quot;&gt;Neil Armstrong&lt;/a&gt;
    and &lt;a href=&quot;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzz_Aldrin&quot; title=&quot;Buzz Aldrin&quot;&gt;Buzz Aldrin&lt;/a&gt;, on the Moon on July 20, 1969, at 20:18 UTC. Armstrong became
    the first to step onto the lunar surface 6 hours later on July 21 at 02:56 UTC.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;Armstrong spent about &lt;s&gt;three and a half&lt;/s&gt; two and a half hours
    outside the spacecraft, Aldrin slightly less; and together they collected 47.5 pounds (21.5&amp;nbsp;kg) of lunar material for return to Earth. A third member of the mission, &lt;a
    href=&quot;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Collins_(astronaut)&quot; title=&quot;Michael Collins (astronaut)&quot;&gt;Michael Collins&lt;/a&gt;, piloted the &lt;a href=&quot;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Command/Service_Module&quot;
    title=&quot;Apollo Command/Service Module&quot;&gt;command&lt;/a&gt; spacecraft alone in lunar orbit until Armstrong and Aldrin returned to it for the trip back to Earth.&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;h2&gt;Broadcasting and &lt;em&gt;quotes&lt;/em&gt; &lt;a id=&quot;quotes&quot; name=&quot;quotes&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/h2&gt; &lt;p&gt;Broadcast on live TV to a world-wide
    audience, Armstrong stepped onto the lunar surface and described the event as:&lt;/p&gt; &lt;blockquote&gt;&lt;p&gt;One small step for [a] man, one giant leap for mankind.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Apollo 11 effectively ended the &lt;a href=&quot;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Race&quot; title=&quot;Space Race&quot;&gt;Space Race&lt;/a&gt; and fulfilled a national
    goal proposed in 1961 by the late U.S. President &lt;a href=&quot;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_F._Kennedy&quot; title=&quot;John F. Kennedy&quot;&gt;John F. Kennedy&lt;/a&gt; in a
    speech before the United States Congress:&lt;/p&gt; &lt;blockquote&gt;&lt;p&gt;[...] before this decade is out, of landing a man on the Moon and returning him safely to the Earth.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt;
    &lt;h2&gt;Technical details &lt;a id=&quot;tech-details&quot; name=&quot;tech-details&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/h2&gt; &lt;table align=&quot;right&quot; border=&quot;1&quot; bordercolor=&quot;#ccc&quot;
    cellpadding=&quot;5&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; style=&quot;border-collapse:collapse;margin:10px 0 10px 15px;&quot;&gt; &lt;caption&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Mission crew&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/caption&gt;
    &lt;thead&gt; &lt;tr&gt; &lt;th scope=&quot;col&quot;&gt;Position&lt;/th&gt; &lt;th scope=&quot;col&quot;&gt;Astronaut&lt;/th&gt; &lt;/tr&gt; &lt;/thead&gt; &lt;tbody&gt; &lt;tr&gt;
    &lt;td&gt;Commander&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt;Neil A. Armstrong&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt; &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td&gt;Command Module Pilot&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt;Michael Collins&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;
    &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td&gt;Lunar Module Pilot&lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt;Edwin &amp;quot;Buzz&amp;quot; E. Aldrin, Jr.&lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt; &lt;/tbody&gt; &lt;/table&gt; &lt;p&gt;Launched by a
    &lt;strong&gt;Saturn V&lt;/strong&gt; rocket from &lt;a href=&quot;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kennedy_Space_Center&quot; title=&quot;Kennedy Space Center&quot;&gt;Kennedy Space
    Center&lt;/a&gt; in Merritt Island, Florida on July 16, Apollo 11 was the fifth manned mission of &lt;a href=&quot;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA&quot; title=&quot;NASA&quot;&gt;NASA&lt;/a&gt;&amp;#39;s
    Apollo program. The Apollo spacecraft had three parts:&lt;/p&gt; &lt;ol&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Command Module&lt;/strong&gt; with a cabin for the three astronauts which was the
    only part which landed back on Earth&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Service Module&lt;/strong&gt; which supported the Command Module with propulsion, electrical power, oxygen and
    water&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Lunar Module&lt;/strong&gt; for landing on the Moon.&lt;/li&gt; &lt;/ol&gt; &lt;p&gt;After being sent to the Moon by the Saturn V&amp;#39;s
    upper stage, the astronauts separated the spacecraft from it and travelled for three days until they entered into lunar orbit. Armstrong and Aldrin then moved into the Lunar Module and
    landed in the &lt;a href=&quot;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mare_Tranquillitatis&quot; title=&quot;Mare Tranquillitatis&quot;&gt;Sea of Tranquility&lt;/a&gt;. They stayed a total of
    about 21 and a half hours on the lunar surface. After lifting off in the upper part of the Lunar Module and rejoining Collins in the Command Module, they returned to Earth and landed
    in the &lt;a href=&quot;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Ocean&quot; title=&quot;Pacific Ocean&quot;&gt;Pacific Ocean&lt;/a&gt; on July 24.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;hr/&gt; &lt;p style=&quot;text-align:
    right;&quot;&gt;&lt;small&gt;Source: &lt;a href=&quot;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_11&quot;&gt;Wikipedia.org&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
    </textarea>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/7v091ebd/

Resource :  https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/readonly.html